# менеджер архивов не видит встроенную видеокарту linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, intel, видеокарта

поставил LinuxMint 19.3 (tricia) система предупредила что видеодрайвер не поставлен
[image: предупреждение]

менеджер драйверов не дает вывод моей интегрированной видюхи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в свою очередь вот что выводит команда:

user@mint-19:~$ lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+:.+([\S+:\S+])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) [8086:8a56] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

подробности

cpu Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz

видеокарта Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1

ядро линукс Linux mint-19 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

собственно, как сделать так чтобы видюха работала? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Linux kernel v5.0 разве имел поддержку Intel Ice Lake? https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Icelake-Gen-11-I Okay.

Comment: Хотите сказать, что мой дистрибутив просто-напросто не поддерживает видюхи 10 поколения?

Answer (score 0):

Обновил версию ядра - минт сам все подхватил, видюха работает. Правда в браузере и других приложениях (а иногда и на рабочем столе) выскакивают артефакты различной степени раздражительности, но это уже совсем другая история